# Sum of Digits works in console but not when returned

Tags: javascript, sum, digits

So I'm doing a codewars challenge and I have no clue why my code isn't working. I'm a beginner so please don't hate on me.

This is my code:

```
function digital_root(n) {
    let str = n.toString()
    let arr = []
    let sum = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      arr.push(str.charAt(i))
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      sum += Number(arr[i])
    }
    let sumStr = sum.toString()
    if (sumStr.length > 1) {
      digital_root(sum)
    } else  if (sumStr.length == 1) {
        return sum
    }
}
```

It works when I console.log it but not when I return the value. I'm trying to learn recursion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When `sumStr.length > 1`  or both the conditions fail, you're not returning anything from the function.

Comment: What value are you passing to the function?

Comment: but there's no way for sumStr to be less than 1 so the only 2 options are either ==1 or >1 right? I'm not understanding correctly

Comment: So the arguments for this function are supposed to be numbers and this is the problem:


Digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number.


Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. The input will be a non-negative integer.


Examples
    16  -->  1 + 6 = 7 ||
   942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 + 5 = 6 ||
132189  -->  1 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 8 + 9 = 24  -->  2 + 4 = 6 ||
493193  -->  4 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 9 + 3 = 29  -->  2 + 9 = 11  -->  1 + 1 = 2

Comment: I understand what the code is doing. I'd like to know what value you are passing to the function when you say it is not returning a value...

Comment: what is input and output samples

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `digital_root(sum)` too, if `sumStr.length > 1` in order to access recursive returned value.

you have to write `return digital_root(sum)` instead of just `digital_root(sum)`.

check below:

```js
function digital_root(n) {
    let str = n.toString()
    let arr = []
    let sum = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      arr.push(str.charAt(i))
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      sum += Number(arr[i])
    }
    let sumStr = sum.toString()
    if (sumStr.length > 1) {
      return digital_root(sum)
    } else  if (sumStr.length == 1) {
        return sum
    }
}

console.log("Digital Root :", digital_root('123456789'));
```

Comment: ok, i understand, and that definitely solved the issue. but why was that the correct syntax?

Comment: if you want that function to return something, then we must write the return keyword, so if there is no conditional operation, then we write the return keyword once and it will return. but if we add conditional operation, then need to return value from both the scenario of success and failure, you wrote in else part, but what about if the condition will be true? it must be returned from there too whether it is a value or a function.

Comment: [check this link](https://cdn.programiz.com/sites/tutorial2program/files/javascript-factorial-working.png), it is not exactly the same but the logic is the same, you will get a more clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems you are missing dealing with the return value of digital_root when you call it recursively. See added "return" statement below.

```
function digital_root(n) {
    let str = n.toString()
    let arr = []
    let sum = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      arr.push(str.charAt(i))
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      sum += Number(arr[i])
    }
    let sumStr = sum.toString()
    if (sumStr.length > 1) {
      // ***** You need to deal with the return value of digital_root when you call it. 
      return digital_root(sum)
    } else  if (sumStr.length == 1) {
        return sum
    }
}
```

Comment: BRO I HATE YOU SO MUCH BUT WHY WAS THAT MISSING CAN YOU EXPLAIN? Sorry, i was a bit exasperated.

Comment: Calm down bro... :) - well, I can't explain why it was missing... you probably didn't add the return. You need to return the value of the calculation to the previous call on the stack. As you were not returning it, it was "undefined" and that was breaking the calc.

Comment: Hey my guy, thank you so very much lol I was so mad yesterday like why didn'i I return it because in my head it made sense but after your explanation it clicked. Appreciate it tons!

Answer (score 0):

However, while JavaScript's functional coding style does support recursive functions, we need to be aware that most JavaScript compilers are not currently optimized to support them safely. Recursion is best applied when you need to call the same function repeatedly with different parameters from within a loop.

Please read this,

[https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/#:~:text=However%2C%20while%20JavaScript's%20functional%20coding,parameters%20from%20within%20a%20loop](https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20while%20JavaScript%27s%20functional%20coding,parameters%20from%20within%20a%20loop).

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'll def read it.